# Is there a way to tell the Borrow Checker that a future will be dropped within scope, so it will be allowed to close over local references?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, borrow-checker

In the following code snippet, a `wrapper` function takes a callback, executes it and returns its result. This works well in sync code, but breaks in async code.

##### Sync version (works):

```rust
use std::future::Future;

fn wrapper<T, R>(
    mut value: T,
    f: impl for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut T) -> R,
) -> R
{
    let result = f(&mut value);
    result
}

async fn func(a: &str) -> String {
    wrapper(a, |a|
        a.to_string()
    )
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a9555382f74abefaebd7428f8faa6ae2)

##### Async Version (fails):

```rust
use std::future::Future;

async fn wrapper<T, R, F>(
    mut value: T,
    f: impl for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut T) -> F,
) -> R
where
    F: Future<Output = R>,
{
    let result = f(&mut value).await;
    result
}

async fn func(a: &str) -> String {
    wrapper(a, |a| async move {
        a.to_string()
    }).await
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1751787c581e06b6841cf9f00aaf3e95)

###### Error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:15:20
   |
15 |       wrapper(a, |a| async move {
   |  _________________--_^
   | |                 ||
   | |                 |return type of closure `[async block@src/lib.rs:15:20: 17:6]` contains a lifetime `'2`
   | |                 has type `&'1 mut &str`
16 | |         a.to_string()
17 | |     }).await
   | |_____^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`

error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to previous error
```

It seems that the borrow checker doesn't allow the `async move` closure to capture the `a` reference, even though the closure execution finishes executing before `wrapper.await` returns and `wrapper.await` is happening fully within the lifetime of `a`, therefore the `a` reference will outlive the lifetime of the closure. What is going on here? And is there a way to fix it?

**Note:** I'm aware that it would work if I put the `a.to_string()` call outside of the `async move` closure and only capture the `String` by value, but that's not the goal. This is a toy example and in my real world example, there are several await calls happening within the closure and I can't move that line out of the closure. Also, `to_string` isn't actually `to_string`, but a function with side effects that cannot be reordered.